# Fastest Way to Combining csv Files Horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 3 large csv files, with size varying from 1.5GB-1.8GB. Each file has different metric columns from each other.

```
File1 (columns):       key, metric1, metric2
File1 (sample values): k1,  m1,      m2
                       k2,  m1,      m2

File2 (columns):       key, metric3, metric4, metric5
File2 (sample values): k1,  m3,      m4,      m5

File3 (columns):       key, metric6, metric7
File3 (sample values): k1,  m6,      m7
                       k2,  m6,      m7
```

I would like to combine these 3 files into one file below:

```
Output (columns):       key, metric1, metric2, metric3, metric4, metric5, metric6, metric7
Output (sample values): k1,  m1,      m2,      m3,      m4,      m5,      m6,      m7
                        k2,  m1,      m2,      null,    null,    null,    m6,      m7
```

I tried to use `pandas` and it's taking 40 mins to complete. I guess it is due to the file size.

Is there any faster way of combing big csv files horizontally?

**EDIT :**

Here below are the codes I used:

```
col_to_keep = ['a','b','c']
file_ptn = os.path.join('raw','*foo_bar*.csv')
files = glob.glob(file_ptn)

try:
        df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.DataFrame.combine_first(left,right), [pd.read_csv(f,dtype={'[UPC]': str}).set_index(sch_inx_region) for f in files])
        df = df[col_to_keep]
        df.to_csv('output.csv', compression = None, encoding = 'utf-8')

except Exception as e:
    msg = '--- [combine] Writing output file failed! Error: '+str(e)
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Post your pandas/python code

Comment: Have you tried to iterate over each file and append the headers into a header array and the values into their own array. Then you may be able to create a new csv file from the arrays.

Comment: One other question: Will the keys from multiple files be repeated. As all three files have k1,k2 as their keys but the output only shows k1,k2. Where are the output keys from? I am guessing k1,k2 repeats.

Comment: @JohnH I posted my codes

Comment: @SurajKothari keys are compiled from all these 3 files. Each file has a different set of keys but 98% keys are overlapping within each file..

Comment: make sure you specify `dtype`. in particular, if you have repeated text strings within a column, read them in as categories. this will not only save memory, but should speed up the `combine_first` process.

Comment: `join` in the shell maybe? `man join`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time is going to be file I/O. Here is non-pandas solution for you to test with:

```
import glob
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)
metrics = []

for csv_filename in glob.glob('foo_bar*.csv'):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r', newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
        key_header, *header = next(csv_input)
        metrics.extend(header)

        for row in csv_input:
            key = data[row[0]]

            for metric, value in zip(header, row[1:]):
                key[metric] = value

metrics = sorted(metrics)            

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow([key_header] + metrics)

    for key in sorted(data.keys()):
        csv_output.writerow([key] + [data[key].get(metric, 'null') for metric in metrics])
```

For your example files, this would create an output CSV file:

```
key,metric1,metric2,metric3,metric4,metric5,metric6,metric7
k1,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7
k2,m1,m2,null,null,null,m6,m7
```

It uses a `defaultdict` to build up dictionaries for each key found in each CSV file, then writes all the results to the output file. If a given key does not have a matching metric `null` is written.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't got a suitable `pandas` answer a week later, maybe have a try with `join` in the shell, using `,` as separator:

```
join -t, file[12].csv | join -t, - file3.csv
```